# rails 3 fb_graph notification causing ssl error in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, ssl, fb-graph

Trying to send a notification with fb_graph gem and rails 3.2. I have done like the docs describe at https://github.com/nov/fb_graph/wiki/notifications:

```
user = FbGraph::User.new('matake')
app = FbGraph::Application.new(APP_ID, :secret => APP_SECRET)

app.notify!(
  user,
  :href => 'http://matake.jp',
  :template => 'Your friend @[12345] achieved new badge!'
)
```

but this returns  SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A: sslv3 alert handshake failure in production server